# Apply woocommerce coupon based on number of products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a coupon with product % discount 100%.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/eqom1u

Product also specified: http://prntscr.com/eqomba

Now i want my coupon to work for purchasing two 1 Private Training.

Case be like: If i add 1 Private Training in cart then coupon applies and i buy a product again next time i should be able to use that  coupon and then only coupon should expire.

Next, If i add two 1 Private Training in cart then coupon applies and while i go for next purchase then coupon should expire cause coupon meets the requirment of two 1 Private Training.

Any one can suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand what you wrote here. please elaborate more with proper English.

Thank You

Comment: What i want actually is to make coupon expire on the basis of it applied to specified number of particular product. Suppose **C** is coupon and **P** is product associated with **C**. I want **C** to expire once it is applied for 2 **P**

Comment: there may be two possibilities. 
1) User is logged in and use coupon 
2) User is not logged in or you are not required to login

if its first condition, then you can add it against each user. and check if user have already used that coupon. 
if its second condition, then you have an email address (at time of checkout) and do the same as in first condition.

Comment: Sorry that is not what i actually want. No need to take care of logged in status. I just want to use **C** multiple times until it is applied for 2 **P**.

Comment: You can use meta to take care of any Coupon. 

You can check if a particular coupon is expired (if it is used for two times) from post_meta table. when a coupon created then set any key let suppose coupon_used_by = 0. and when someone applies a coupon then check and increment. 

You can also track a coupon, on what products a particular coupon is applied from post_meta.

Comment: Sorry that does not help anymore in my case. Ain't there any way within the coupon system? Creating meta field and other stuffs wont make things smooth.